# Ideas on a cleaner way to write this click to hide/show jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs I'm hiding/showing based on click of another div. Right now, it's rather messy, as I have to duplicate a ton of code every time a new div is added. I'm looking for suggestions on ways to clean it up. Maybe use something like data attributes instead of literal IDs to streamline things?

My HTML:

```
<div aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuFilters" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdownMenuFilters p-0 show" x-placement="bottom-end" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(-106px, 56px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
<ul class="list-unstyled m-4 bg-white">
    <li id="schoolsProgramsFilter" class="py-1">Schools &amp; Programs</li>
    <li id="difficultyFilter" class="py-1">Admission Difficulty</li>
    <li id="gpaFilter" class="py-1">GPA</li>
    <li id="satFilter" class="py-1">SAT</li>
    <li id="actFilter" class="py-1">ACT</li>
    <li id="sizeFilter" class="py-1">School Size</li>
    <li id="settingFilter" class="py-1">Setting</li>
</ul>
<div id="schoolsProgramsFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...
</div>
<div id="difficultyFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...
</div>
<div id="gpaFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...
</div>
<div id="satFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...
</div>
<div id="actFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...
</div>
<div id="sizeFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
   ... content ...
</div>
<div id="settingFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...
</div>
```

MY JQUERY:

```
$("#schoolsProgramsFilter").click(function () {
        if($(".openSubMenu").hasClass("popped")) {
            $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
        }
        $("#schoolsProgramsFilterSub").toggleClass("popped");
    });

    $("#difficultyFilter").click(function () {
        if($(".openSubMenu").hasClass("popped")) {
            $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
        }
        $("#difficultyFilterSub").toggleClass("popped");
    });

    $("#gpaFilter").click(function () {
        if($(".openSubMenu").hasClass("popped")) {
            $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
        }
        $("#gpaFilterSub").toggleClass("popped");
    });

    $("#satFilter").click(function () {
        if($(".openSubMenu").hasClass("popped")) {
            $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
        }
        $("#satFilterSub").toggleClass("popped");
    });

    $("#actFilter").click(function () {
        if($(".openSubMenu").hasClass("popped")) {
            $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
        }
        $("#actFilterSub").toggleClass("popped");
    });

    $("#sizeFilter").click(function () {
        if($(".dropdownMenuFilters ul li").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".dropdownMenuFilters ul li").removeClass("active");
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        if($(".openSubMenu").hasClass("popped")) {
            $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
        }
        $("#sizeFilterSub").toggleClass("popped");
    });

    $("#settingFilter").click(function () {
        if($(".openSubMenu").hasClass("popped")) {
            $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
        }
        $("#settingFilterSub").toggleClass("popped");
    });
```

Comment: Instead of attaching an event to each `id`, just attach _one_ event to their common identifier: their _class_. You could then fetch the id using `this` and add `"Sub"` to select the element you want.. Or even better, use `data` attributes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Just because a question is on-topic at another site, does **not** mean it is off topic for this one. The rule itself that you're acknowledging (and the one that I assume caused you to downvote my answer) specifically says: *"**If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow**, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site."*. This question *is* on topic for Stack Overflow, despite the fact that it may be more *specific* to another site.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu More specifically, from [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users): *"Before referring a Stack Overflow user to Code Review, consider: **Is it really off-topic for Stack Overflow?** Just because a question is said to have "working code" and seems to be on-topic on Code Review, doesn't mean that it is automatically off-topic for Stack Overflow."*

Comment: @Tyler, I haven't down-voted your answer. Yet. I down-voted Zakaria's as I believe he, being the highest rep user, should set the example. Probably thinking you down-voted him, he might have down-voted you. However, I do believe questions of type: *"i wrote this code badly, write it pro for me"* are generally aimed at getting help for a specific case, rather than the general one and are therefore not useful for future users and should be discouraged. I guess we might agree the subject is debatable and while you might find some questions on or off topic others might not.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I don't agree that the subject is "debatable", quite honestly, at least not in this specific case. I think that both marking this question as "off-topic" and punishing the answers therein is simply incorrect and a misunderstanding of the rules, as pointed out in various threads on meta and even the guide itself (the link I posted and quoted above).

Comment: If you're going to make a case that this user hasn't made a legitimate enough attempt and as such, this is off-topic, then I don't take as much exception to that. Although, in such a case, I'd say your comment and closure vote (*"...because it belongs on Code Review"*) was if anything, misleading.

Comment: I am entitled to my opinion on what adds to the evolution or demise of SO as a tool. I honestly believe encouraging questions generally treating SO as a code-writing service are detrimental to its evolution in "making web better", which is its mission statement. And I am entitled at up-voting q&a which, in my view add value to the community and down-voting those which don't. You are free to disagree. You should know by now this is not personal, but about principles for me. I myself have a lot of q&a's which should be down-voted on the same criteria. Feel free to return the favor.

Comment: In all honesty, I find it hard to draw the line between helping specific cases, clearly doing a favor to OP and refusing to do so on the sole basis their question is not aimed at helping others. And sometimes I make the same call as you made today, risking being down-voted, which I sometimes do get, and still think it was worth it. Sometimes. To sum it up, it wasn't only the fact it's asking for a code-review. And I stand by my vote. I hope you don't mind. Too much. :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Well I appreciate you taking the time to explain your side of things. I think you and I do see things the same in terms of what makes SO better or worse, and given that explanation, I don't think I would have argued that you were in the wrong. The stance I'd taken was merely based on my understanding that you marked this off-topic and downvoted the answers solely based on the fact that it fit better somewhere else, rather than "This is off-topic, but might fit better somewhere else", which i'm more willing to accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180690/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-tyler-roper).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first step is to use just one event handler on the common class, instead of one on each ID.

You could then grab the `id` and append `"Sub"` to it to select the corresponding element...

```
$(".py-1").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
    $("#" + id + "Sub").addClass("popped");
});
```

---

Or, if you didn't want to depend on concatenating the ID's (so that you could change ID's without fear of breaking them), you could use `data` attributes...

```
<div id="schoolsProgramsFilterSub" ... data-for="schoolsProgramsFilter">
```

```
$(".py-1").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".openSubMenu").removeClass("popped");
    $("[data-for=" + id + "]").addClass("popped");
});
```

This method will grab the clicked element's ID, and look for an element with the corresponding `data-for` attribute.

For example, clicking an element with `id="schoolsProgramsFilter"` will reveal any element that has `data-for="schoolsProgramsFilter"` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add single on click listener on parent and utilise event bubbling. When a child element is clicked you will get it's id using which you can change appropriate classes.

Advantage: This approach adds only one event listener and your code is significantly reduced.

```
$(".list-styled").click(function (e) {
    if($(`#${e.target.id} .openSubMenu`).hasClass("popped")) {
        $(`#${e.target.id} .openSubMenu`).removeClass("popped");
    }
    $(`#${e.target.id}Sub`).toggleClass("popped");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the common classes instead, you could remove the class `popped` from all the submenu divs but not the related to the actual clicked element using `.not(the_current)` like:

```
$(".openSubMenu").not(sub_menu).removeClass("popped");
```

Then you could simply toggle the class using:

```
sub_menu.toggleClass("popped");
```

```js
$(".py-1").click(function() {
  var sub_menu = $('#' + this.id + 'Sub');

  $(".openSubMenu").not(sub_menu).removeClass("popped");
  sub_menu.toggleClass("popped");
});
```

```css
.p-4 {
  display: none;
}

.popped {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuFilters" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdownMenuFilters p-0 show" x-placement="bottom-end">
  <ul class="list-unstyled m-4 bg-white">
    <li id="schoolsProgramsFilter" class="py-1">Schools &amp; Programs</li>
    <li id="difficultyFilter" class="py-1">Admission Difficulty</li>
    <li id="gpaFilter" class="py-1">GPA</li>
    <li id="satFilter" class="py-1">SAT</li>
    <li id="actFilter" class="py-1">ACT</li>
    <li id="sizeFilter" class="py-1">School Size</li>
    <li id="settingFilter" class="py-1">Setting</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="schoolsProgramsFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...1
  </div>
  <div id="difficultyFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...2
  </div>
  <div id="gpaFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...3
  </div>
  <div id="satFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...4
  </div>
  <div id="actFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...5
  </div>
  <div id="sizeFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...6
  </div>
  <div id="settingFilterSub" class="openSubMenu p-4 rounded">
    ... content ...7
  </div>
```

Comment: By answering off-topic questions you are inviting more off-topic questions, which leads to an overall decrease in SO's content quality. There is a dedicated community for code review.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu This question is not off-topic. Please see my comment on the OP.